# Proving $\ker(g)=\ker(f)\cap {\rm Im}(f)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $f$ an endomorphism $g=f_{|{\rm Im}(f)}$ the restriction of $g$ on the subspace ${\rm Im}(f)$.

How can I prove that $\ker(g)=\ker(f)\cap {\rm Im}(f)$?

Comment: Just apply the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in \ker g$, then $x\in {\rm Im} f$ and $g(x)=f(x)=0$, so $x\in \ker f\cap {\rm Im} f$. If $x\in \ker f\cap {\rm Im} f$, then $f(x)=0$ and $x\in {\rm Im} f$, so $g(x)=f(x)=0$ then $x\in \ker g$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f\colon V\to W$ be a linear map and $U$ a subspace of $V$. Denote by $g$ the restriction of $f$ to $U$. Then
$$
\ker g=\{x\in U:g(x)=0\}=\{x\in U: x\in\ker f\}=\ker f\cap U.
$$